# create a register

Tags: dictionary, tree, ocaml

I have to create a type tree which would be used to store words, like every node of the tree would hold a letter and the list of the next characters (so words with the same root would share the same "part/branch of the tree). the tree is basically a n-ary one, used as a dictionnary.
All using Caml language

Comment: Seems you want to implement [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: Actually, my answer starts with `module` so you were wrong about that. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know if it's a homework or not but I'll still answer :

First, we need to define a signature type for *letters*.

```
module type LS = sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
end
```

Then, we need to define our structure :

```
module Make (L : LS) = struct

  module M = Map.Make(L)

  type elt = L.t list
  type t = { word : bool; branches : t M.t }

  let empty = { word = false; branches = M.empty }

  let is_empty t = not t.word && M.is_empty t.branches

  let rec mem x t =
    match x with
      | [] -> t.word
      | c :: cl -> try mem cl (M.find c t.branches)
        with Not_found -> false

  let rec add x t =
    match x with
      | [] -> if t.word then t else { t with word = true }
      | c :: cl ->
        let b = try M.find c t.branches with Not_found -> empty in
        { t with branches = M.add c (add cl b) t.branches }
end
```

---

Now, step by step :

- `module Make (L : LS) = struct` is a functor that will return a new module if we give it a module of type `LS` as an argument
- `module M = Map.Make(L)
  type elt = L.t list
  type t = { word : bool; branches : t M.t }` 
  This is the complex point, once you have it, everything begins clear. We need to represent a node (as you can see in the [Wikipedia page of tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)). My representation is this : a node is

  - a truth value stating that this node represent a word (which means that all the letters from the root to this node form a word)
  - the branches that goes from it. To represent this branches, I need a dictionary and luckily there's a `Map` *functor* in OCaml. So, my field `branches` is a field associating to some letters a `trie` (which is why I wrote that `branches : t M.t`). An element is then a list of letters and you'll find out why I chose this type rather than a `string`.
- `let empty = { word = false; branches = M.empty }` the empty trie is the record with no branches (so, just the root), and this root is not a word (so `word = false`) (same idea for `is_empty`)
- `let rec mem x t =
   match x with
     | [] -> t.word
     | c :: cl -> try mem cl (M.find c t.branches)
       with Not_found -> false`

  Here it becomes interesting. My word being a list of letters, if I want to know if a word is in my trie, I need to make a recursive functions going through this list.

  - If I reached the point where my list is empty it means that I reached a node where the path from the root to it is composed by all the letters of my word. I just need to know, then, if the value `word` at this node is `true` or `false`.
  - If I still have at least one letter I need to find the branch corresponding to this letter.

    - If I find this branch (which will be a trie), I just need to make a recursive call to find the rest of the word (`cl`) in it
    - If I don't find it I know that my word doesn't exist in my trie so I can return false.
- `let rec add x t =
     match x with
       | [] -> if t.word then t else { t with word = true }
       | c :: cl ->
         let b = try M.find c t.branches with Not_found -> empty in
         { t with branches = M.add c (add cl b) t.branches }`

  Same idea. If I want to add a word :

  - If my list is empty it means that I added all the letters and I've reached the node corresponding to my word. In that case, if `word` is already `true` it means that this word was already added, I don't do anything. If `word` is `false` I just return the same branch (trie) but with `word` equal to `true`.
  - If my list contains at least a letter `c`, I find in the current node the branch corresponding to it (`try M.find c t.branches with Not_found -> empty`) and I there's no such branch, I just return an empty one and then I recursively add the rest of my letters to this branch and add this new branch to the branches of my current node associated to the letter `c` (if this branch already existed, it will be replaced since I use a dictionary)

---

[image: Example of a trie and its evolutione]

Here, we start with the empty trie and we add the word *to*, *top* and *tea*.

---

In case we don't want to use *functors*, we can do it this way :

```
  type elt = char list
  type t = { word : bool; branches : (char * t) list }

  let empty = { word = false; branches = [] }

  let is_empty t = not t.word && t.branches = []

  let find c l = 
    let rec aux = function
      | [] -> raise Not_found
      | (c', t) :: tl when c' = c -> t
      | _ :: tl -> aux tl
    in aux l

  let rec mem x t =
    match x with
      | [] -> t.word
      | c :: cl -> try mem cl (find c t.branches)
        with Not_found -> false

  let rec add x t =
    match x with
      | [] -> if t.word then t else { t with word = true }
      | c :: cl ->
        let b = try find c t.branches with Not_found -> empty in
        { t with branches = (c, (add cl b)) :: t.branches }
```

Comment: yoooo so my teacher's mad as hell, I don't even know what a fonctor is lol ! I mean really, he didn't told us about it. does it mean that there's a way to answer that question without using it ? maybe, I don't know. but yes that's a homework, and thanks a lot for your help

Comment: And you can't use `Map` either?

Comment: yes i think I can't, but the problem is there might be no other way to do it than the way you did. And I've been introduced to Ocaml only 2 months ago...

Comment: Well, if your teacher gave you this work to do there must be another way. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: probably, because we (his students) are not supposed to be that good in OCaml already