# Trying to understand how to implement Tries with hash tables in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, hashtable, trie

I'm trying to understand how to implement Tries with hash tables in Ocaml. It's the excercise W06 04 from the MOOC "Introduction to Functional Programming in OCaml" in https://www.fun-mooc.fr/.

I really appreciate if someone can help me to understand how to implement the recursive Tries using the imperative hash tables.

The course has ended, I just want to understand.

This is what I'm trying (module GenericTrie and the template of module Trie was given, we had to instantiate Hashtbl.Make functor and implement empty, lookup and insert):

```
module type GenericTrie = sig
  type 'a char_table
  type 'a trie = Trie of 'a option * 'a trie char_table
  val empty : unit -> 'a trie
  val insert : 'a trie -> string -> 'a -> 'a trie
  val lookup : 'a trie -> string -> 'a option
end

module CharHashedType = struct
  type t = char
  let equal a b = a = b
  let hash a = Hashtbl.hash a
end

module CharHashtbl  = Hashtbl.Make(CharHashedType)

module Trie : GenericTrie with type 'a char_table = 'a CharHashtbl.t =
  struct
    type 'a char_table = 'a CharHashtbl.t
    type 'a trie = Trie of 'a option * 'a trie char_table

    let empty () =
      Trie (None, CharHashtbl.create 10)
    ;;

    let lookup trie w =
      let len = String.length w in
      let rec lookup' trie' idx =
        if idx >= len then let Trie (x, _) = trie' in x
        else
          let Trie (_, table) = trie' in
          if CharHashtbl.mem table w.[idx] then
            lookup' (CharHashtbl.find table w.[idx]) (idx + 1)
          else raise Not_found
      in
      lookup' trie 0
    ;;

    let insert trie w v =

    ;;
  end
```

Comment: It's difficult to help without seeing the definition of the module `CharHashtbl`.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Thanks, I edited the question and I added the code that I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903424/create-a-register/42905583#42905583), the only difference is that instead of having a `Map` you have a `Hashtbl`

So, from what I understand, your trie associates to a `string` an `'a option` which means that you can store the resulting string or a boolean or anything else but we don't care about that.

First, I would have written

```
type 'a trie = {value : 'a option;
                children : 'a trie char_table}
```

Because I find it strange to use a constructor if you just need one and the record will help for the future :

```
module Trie : GenericTrie with type 'a char_table = 'a CharHashtbl.t = struct
  type 'a char_table = 'a CharHashtbl.t
  type 'a trie = {value : 'a option;
                  children : 'a trie char_table}

  let empty () =
    {value = None; children = CharHashtbl.create 10}
  ;;


  let lookup trie w =
    let len = String.length w in
    let rec lookup' {value; children} idx =
      if idx >= len then value
      else
        let char = w.[idx] in
        let child = CharHashtbl.find children char in
        lookup' child (idx + 1)
    in
    lookup' trie 0
  ;;
```

I simplified `lookup` (note that writing `if Module.mem ... then Module.find ... else raise Not_found` is strictly equivalent to `Module.find ...`)

Then, what about `insert`? The algorithm is pretty simple :

- if I reached the last letter of my string, I associate to it the value
- if not, either there's one child associated to the current letter and I recursively go through this branch or there's not and I need to create this branch.

Which, in OCaml, gives :

```
  let insert trie w v =
    let len = String.length w in
    let rec aux trie idx =
      if idx >= len then {trie with value = Some v}
      else
        let char = w.[idx] in
        let child = try CharHashtbl.find trie.children char
          with Not_found -> empty () in
        let child' = aux child (idx + 1) in
        CharHashtbl.add trie.children char child';
        trie
    in aux trie 0
  ;;
```

---

As a side note, I'd like to point out the fact that it's really strange to mix persistent and mutable datatypes. My preference, in this case, would be this :

```
module type GenericTrie = sig
  type 'a char_table
  type 'a trie = {mutable value : 'a option;
                  children : 'a trie char_table}
  val empty : unit -> 'a trie
  val insert : 'a trie -> string -> 'a -> unit
  val lookup : 'a trie -> string -> 'a option
end;;

module CharHashedType = struct
  type t = char
  let equal a b = a = b
  let hash a = Hashtbl.hash a
end;;

module CharHashtbl  = Hashtbl.Make(CharHashedType)

module Trie : GenericTrie with type 'a char_table = 'a CharHashtbl.t = struct
  type 'a char_table = 'a CharHashtbl.t
  type 'a trie = {mutable value : 'a option;
                  children : 'a trie char_table}

  let empty () =
    {value = None; children = CharHashtbl.create 10}
  ;;

  let lookup trie w =
    let len = String.length w in
    let rec lookup' {value; children} idx =
      if idx >= len then value
      else
        let char = w.[idx] in
        let child = CharHashtbl.find children char in
        lookup' child (idx + 1)
    in
    lookup' trie 0
  ;;

  let insert trie w v =
    let len = String.length w in
    let rec aux trie idx =
      if idx >= len then trie.value <- Some v
      else
        let char = w.[idx] in
        let child = try CharHashtbl.find trie.children char
          with Not_found ->
            let child = empty () in
            CharHashtbl.add trie.children char child;
            child
        in
        aux child (idx + 1)
    in aux trie 0
  ;;
```

---

In both cases, let's print it with this function :

```
let (t : string Trie.trie) = Trie.empty ();;

let rec pp fmt trie =
  let open Trie in
  let {value; children} = trie in
  Format.fprintf fmt "@[<v 1>";
  (match value with
    | None -> Format.fprintf fmt "None"
    | Some s -> Format.fprintf fmt "Some %s" s
  );
  CharHashtbl.iter (fun char trie ->
    Format.fprintf fmt "@ %c@ %a" char pp trie
  ) children;
  Format.fprintf fmt "@]"

let () = 
  Trie.insert t "foo" "foo";
  Trie.insert t "fol" "fol";
  Trie.insert t "far" "far";
  Format.printf "%a@." pp t
```

I'll have this output :

```
None
 f
 None
  o
  None
   o
   Some foo
   l
   Some fol
  a
  None
   r
   Some far
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this weekend I'm going to try to understand your solution and adapt it to the requirements. The excercise ask to implement the trie with this type signature: `type 'a trie = Trie of 'a option * 'a trie char_table` and `'a trie char_table` is 'a CharHashtbl.t` In a previous excercise we had to implement the trie with this type: `type trie = Trie of int option * char_to_children`
and `char_to_children = (char * trie) list`

Comment: I still can't see why you have to use a constructor to do this. It's bad design since you only have one type. Anyway, you can adapt my answer easily by changing the record. And I still don't agree with the use of mutable and persistent date types in the same type. Good luck and don't forget to accept answers. ;-)

Comment: Yes, for me it's really confusing but that is what they ask for... I didn't had problems to implement a trie with `(char * trie) list`, but trying to do that with hash table is really confusing.

Comment: Of course it was easier with lists, because lists are persistent which is consistent with the rest of the program. Hashtables are not and there lies the problem! ;-)